# Run command over remote ssh virtual machine and store response locally

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I am calling  a remote ssh through putty and hitting some commands say 'ls' now I want to be able to store its response into a text file into my local system from which I am making remote ssh call ? is this possible ? if so plz share

*plink remotessh -l user -pw password*

**ls**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but not with Putty as far as I am aware. If you can run a cygwin environment and use ssh directly you could do the following:

```
ssh user@host -- ls > output.txt
```

**With plink as per @Ferrybig's comment** (thanks!)

```
plink user@host -- ls > output.txt
```

Comment: your solution stores on vm not on my local